# How can I fix file.exists() on mac?

Tags: c#, macos

I'm using Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac and I'm having trouble dealing with C#'s file.exists() method. I'm also quite new to the language.

```
if (!File.Exists("Content/" + path)) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File " + path + " not found in Content folder.");
}
```

Here I'm trying to see if an image file exists in a directory named "Content", but the method "File.Exists()" always returns false even though the file does exist in the directory.

What's more, the code below this which will access the same "path" crashes the program because it doesn't detect the file (and yes, I'm using OpenTK as well but that's most likely irrelevant).

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("Content/" + path);
```

Some answers say that I may have spelling mistakes or unwanted spaces, but I know very well that this isn't happening with me.

Some sources say to run the project as an administrator or "grant permissions" but even after days of searching and searching around the internet on how to do them I still haven't found anything helpful.

Some sources talk about the idea that running in x86 gives different results to x64 and I should try building the program in 64-bit, but:

1. I don't know how to do that and I haven't found any information which helps me with this.
2. I'm not even sure what "x" I'm running the project on.

How do I fix this problem in OSX?
(I also hope that I've explained myself well because this could be a little complicated)

EDIT #1: From the comments I've seen so far, I believe that it would be more helpful to show the hierarchy of my project

```
otk1 (Directory)
    otk1 (Directory)
        References (Directory)
        Packages (Directory)
        Content (Directory)
            image.jpg (Image file - The one I'm trying to open)
        ContentPipe.cs (Csharp file which tries to access the Content directory)
        GameClass.cs
        OpenTK.dll.config
        packages.config
        Program.cs
```

Comment: Use `System.IO.Path.Combine()` to build directory and file paths from fragments, not string concatenation of words and slashes. Also, by not starting your path with a slash, this will surely make the path relative to the current working directory. Is that what you intended? Do you know for sure that the working directory is set to what you expect?

Comment: Is the `Content/` a child folder in your application? You _may_ have to provide the full path otherwise. Hth..

Comment: What is the result of `File.Exists("Content");` and `Directory.Exists("Content");`?

Comment: Environment.CurrentDirectory is the worst global variable imaginable.  You don't directly control its initial value, you can't tell when it changes.  Don't use it, always use a fully specified path.  Usually computed from Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location, the directory in which your program is stored.

Comment: Caius Jard - I'll certainly look into Path.Combine() and I did want to make the path relative to the current working directory. The hierarchy looks like what's in the edited question post.

Comment: EsDF - Yes, Content/ is a child folder in the application, and after providing the full path, it worked! But what If I wanted to send a copy of this project to someone else's computer? The "full directory" would break wouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I needed to use the entire path to the image file or it wouldn't work.

Eg (This is on mac):

```
File.Exists("/Users/usr/.../Project/.../file.ext")
```